# Get data from the database using mvc with foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, model-view-controller, foreach

I am trying to retrieve data from the database and write the records out, but i am getting an error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_uaarpxja.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Database model **PastaModel.cs**

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Itemid { get; set; }
    public string Itemname { get; set; }
    public int Itemprice { get; set; }
    public int Currentstock { get; set; }
    public string Itemtype { get; set; }
    public string pictureURL { get; set; }
}

public class PastaContext : DbContext
{

    public PastaContext()
        : base("name=PastaModel")
    {
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

}
```

Controller **ItemController.cs**

```
public class ItemController : Controller
{

    private PastaContext db = new PastaContext();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

View **Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Oblig1.Models.Item>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<br />
<br />

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{

     <p>@item.Itemname</p>

}


</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error in this line `@foreach (var item in Model) {`

Edit: Added DbContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are not injecting anything in your view from controller from where you are returning view.

and your view expecting `IEnumerable<Oblig1.Models.Item>` from your controller but as you are not passing model from controller the view gets null in `Model`.

try below code :-

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = db.Items.ToList(); ////Your model that you want to pass
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Then i getting, `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Oblig1.Models.Item]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Oblig1.Models.Item'.` when i try it.

Comment: New error... `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Oblig1.Models.Item]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Oblig1.Models.Item'` @Neel

Comment: have you made changes in ur view ? @mv700 your view expecting ienumerable

Comment: is this first line of ur view "@model IEnumerable<Oblig1.Models.Item>"
? @mv700

Comment: Yes, `@model IEnumerable<Oblig1.Models.Item>` @Neel

Comment: if it is IEnumerable<Oblig1.Models.Item> then why in error its saying its expecting 'Oblig1.Models.Item'? @mv700

Comment: I don't have a clue, it sounds like it should be working... @Neel

Comment: It's working now. It was the layout which was ruining everything. Thanks! @Neel

Comment: when are you getting this error? while GET or POST? as per my understanding in every GET request you will have this error, because you are using same view for both the request and in GET request you are not providing model.